# How to write in a compact form these inequalities?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, notation

I need some help with notations. Suppose that the inequality
$$ 0\leq s_i\leq p_i p_j^{\ast} \quad\mbox{ for } i, j =1, 2 \mbox{ and } i\neq j$$
holds, where $p^{\ast}$ denote the Sobolev critical exponent. I need to write in "compact form" (I mean as in the inequality above) the following inequalities
$$ 1<s_3<p_1^{\ast}, \quad 1<s_4<p_2^{\ast}, \quad 1< s_5 <p_2^{\ast},\quad 1<s_6<p_1^{\ast}.$$

Could anyone please help me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: So you want to write 4 inequalities as one inequality? Why would you be interested in that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Via polynomial interpolation:
$$1<s_k<p^*_{(-k^2 + 9 k - 16)/2} \quad \text{for $k\in\{3,4,5,6\}$}$$

Using mod:
$$1<s_k<p^*_{a_k} \quad \text{for $k\in\{3,4,5,6\}$},$$
where $a_k=\begin{cases}1 &\text{if $k \pmod 3 = 0$}\\2 &\text{otherwise} \end{cases}$

Comment: thank you for the answer, I will accept it as soon as possible. I would like to ask you if it is possible to generalize this result. I mean, if I consider $i, j =1,\dots, m$ with $m\geq2$, $m$ finite, it is possible to generalize your answer to $s_{2m}$-exponents? I am interested only in mod notation.

Comment: What is the general pattern you want to capture?

Comment: Sorry RobPratt, I tried to explain here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3834864/it-is-possible-to-compact-this-notation